# Ajax data table reload with filter data using springboot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, datatable

I have data table which is fetching values from spring-boot controller.in my JSP page there are some filter criteria, on click of filter apply I am able to call controller GET request but on returning to JSP page data-table is not reloading with filter data.
JSP file view-tasks.jsp:

```
<c:forEach var="task" items="${taskList}" varStatus="status">
                        <tr>
                            
                            <td class="col-md-auto">${task.taskId}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-auto">${task.status}</td>
                            <td class="col-md-auto">${task.assignTo}</td>
                            
</tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

Filter button and ajax call:

```
<button class="btn-primary" type="BUTTON" id="fetchTasks" value="Apply" style="margin-left: 20px; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold;" onclick="onApply();">Apply</button>

function onApply()
    {
    var taskGroup = document.getElementById("taskGroup").value;
    var taskType = document.getElementById("taskType").value;
    var taskStatus = document.getElementById("taskStatus").value;
var tableData = $("#dataTableTask").DataTable;
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/taskmgmtqueue/tasks",
     data: { taskGroup: taskGroup, taskType: taskType , status: taskStatus } ,
      success:function(data)
                        {
                            tableData.ajax.reload();
                        }
})
            
    }

    (function($) {
                var oTable = $('#dataTableTask').DataTable({
                    "pageLength" : -1,
                    "autoWidth": false,
                    "bFilter" : true,
                    "lengthMenu" : [ [ -1, 5, 10, 25 ], [ "All", 5, 10, 25 ] ],
                    "aaSorting": []
                });     
            })(jQuery);
```

Controller class:

```
@GetMapping("/tasks")
    public String viewTasks(Model model,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer taskGroup,
            @RequestParam(defaultValue = "0") Integer taskType,@RequestParam(defaultValue = "Open") String status) {

// some operations

model.addAttribute("taskList", taskList);
        model.addAttribute("userType", userType);
        return "view-tasks";
    }
```